# Woocommerce connecting From price.php to functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, overriding, cart, price

How do I retrieve select input from price.php to functions.php?

Here is my price.php code, (hresults is taken from the database):

```
<select class="form-control" id="hotel" name="hotel">
    <?php

        foreach ( $hresults as $hresult ) { 
            echo "<option>" . $hresult->hotel . " + ₱" . $hresult->hotelprice . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Here is the functions.php code:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

    $pricesplit = explode("$",$_POST['hotel']);
    $hotelprice = (int) $pricesplit;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) { 

      $quantity = floatval( $value['quantity'] );
      $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
      $value['data']->price = ( ( $orgPrice + $hotelprice ) * $quantity );

    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
```

My question is, how do I retrieve the hotel select input and use it for calculations overriding the woocommerce price?

[image]

First the user selects the hotel and airfare, which has a price on their side. Then, then once the user adds it to the cart, it overrides the price. Depending on the chosen hotel and airport.

For example:

- Airport: China - $400
- Hotel: Radisson - $500
- TOTAL = ( Base Fare + Airport + Hotel ) * Item Quantity

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve the hotel select input"? Do you want the html mark up of the select field or you want to use the "$hresult" variable value in your calculation?

Comment: the name of the select is "hotel"  <select class="form-control" id="hotel" name="hotel">. Can I use $pricesplit = explode("$",$_POST['hotel']); in the functions php?

Comment: No. You can not use it like that. I mean even if you use it, you will not get the desired value.

Comment: any other ways for me to get the select input value on the functions.php?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Based on that some body can suggest someting

Comment: Edited the question above, with screenshots added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup in your price.php is not correct. The "options" in select field are missing their respective values. That is why you are not getting the price value from the select field. Code in your price.php should be as follows.

```
<select class="form-control" id="hotel" name="hotel">
    <?php
        foreach ( $hresults as $hresult ) { 
            echo '<option value="<?php echo($hresult->hotelprice); ?>">' . $hresult->hotel . ' + ₱' . $hresult->hotelprice . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I hope this will solve your problem. Note the change in use of double quotes (") and single quote (').